# Linux terminal with full keyboard support?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, ncurses, libtermkey

I made a text editor and I want to port it to Linux such that I can use it remotely via SSH. I don't know much about Linux terminals, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, because I just can't believe that in 2013 there's still no way for a remote terminal to distinguish between Ctrl+M and Enter, or between Ctrl+H and Backspace, or even get any events at all for Ctrl+Left/Right/Up/Down, and so on. I tried ncurses and libtermkey to no avail. The question is, is there any effort or discussion in the Linux community on modernizing or replacing the linux terminal protocol(s) to something that supports full keyboard and mouse interaction and possibly full color, i.e. something that would allow for text user-interfaces without huge usability compromises?

Comment: Try using the keypad function which gives different values for special keys, CtrlM and enter are the same, but backspace and Ctrl h and Ctrl left etc give different values. There are also mouse functions, e.g getmouse

Comment: keypad(on) doesn't solve much, there's still lots of missing key combinations and duplicate key combinations. best I could find is termbox which solves some of those (still far from perfect), but has no mouse support. Anyway, I'm actually looking for a replacement of the whole vt100 emulation approach which I think can't be saved (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Linux console terminal just doesn't support this, full stop. If you want to try raising a patch, you could have a go at implementing the full CSI-encoded reporting scheme. It is documented [here](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/).

libtermkey will recognise the key sequences if sent, but the fix has to go into the terminal first of all to send them in the first place.

Comment: Hi LeoNerd I read your page and know about libtermkey. Unfortunately, as you say, until xterm, linux kernel and putty all start sending those CSI codes, we're stuck. Besides, what I'm talking about is something to replace the whole VT102 emulation idea altogether. It takes few days to code a I/O protocol for terminals with full keyboard and mouse support and text and colors. A protocol with a far simpler API than curses, and far simpler implementation. I'm not sure why nobody had thought about it so far.